# How to store Editable GridView values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, gridview

Here I am using GridView Control..My output screen is this..
[image]

Here how to calculate  the "Total" and how to store this data to database when I am clicking the "submit" button.

My code is here..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("S.No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Article No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Order Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UOM", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rate", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Currency", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["S.No"] = 1;
        dr["Article No"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Item Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Order Quantity"] = 0;
        dr["UOM"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Rate"] = 0;
        dr["Currency"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
        box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
        box2.DataValueField = "Description";
        box2.DataBind();
        box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");


        DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box12.DataTextField = "Name";
        box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box12.DataBind();
        box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box13.DataTextField = "Name";
        box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box13.DataBind();
        box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box14.DataTextField = "Name";
        box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box14.DataBind();
        box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");
    }

}


public void addnewrow()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;



        decimal a = 0.00M;

        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //extract the TextBox values
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
            TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
            TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
            TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
            Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
            TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
            TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
            TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
            Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
            DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
            Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
            TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
            TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
            TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
            Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
            DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
            DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
            DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
            Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
            TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
            TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
            TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");

            TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["S.No"] = i + 1;


            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Article No"] = box2.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box3.Text + "," + box4.Text + "," + box5.Text + "," + box6.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Order Quantity"] = box8.Text + "," + box9.Text + "," + box10.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["UOM"] = box12.Text + "," + box13.Text + "," + box14.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Rate"] = box16.Text + "," + box17.Text + "," + box18.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Currency"] = box20.Text + "," + box21.Text + "," + box22.Text;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Amount"] = box24.Text + "," + box25.Text + "," + box26.Text;




            a = a + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box24.Text));
            a = a + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box25.Text));
            a = a + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box26.Text));


            box27.Text = Convert.ToString(a);



            rowIndex++;
        }
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dtCurrentTable;

        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();




        for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
            box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
            box2.DataValueField = "Description";
            box2.DataBind();
            box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box12.DataTextField = "Name";
            box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box12.DataBind();
            box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box13.DataTextField = "Name";
            box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box13.DataBind();
            box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
            box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box14.DataTextField = "Name";
            box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box14.DataBind();
            box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            }


        }
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
                Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
                TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
                TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
                Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
                DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
                Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
                TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
                TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
                TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
                Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
                DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
                DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
                DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
                Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
                TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
                TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
                TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");

                TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["S.No"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Article No"].ToString();

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box3.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box4.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box5.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                    box6.Text = strDesc[3].ToString();
                }

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Order Quantity"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Order Quantity"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box8.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box9.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box10.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["UOM"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["UOM"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box12.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box13.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box14.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Rate"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Rate"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box16.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box17.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box18.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Currency"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Currency"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box20.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box21.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box22.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }

                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Amount"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Amount"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box24.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box25.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box26.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();

                }



                rowIndex++;

            }
        }
    }
}

//DropDownList Selection Change..
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box3.Text = box2.SelectedItem.Value;
        }

}

protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.Text = box12.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.Text = box13.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.Text = box14.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}



protected void DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
        box20.Text = box20.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
        TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
        TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");

        box24.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box16.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box8.Text)).ToString();

    }

}


protected void DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
        box21.Text = box21.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
        TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
        TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
        box25.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box17.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box9.Text)).ToString();
    }
}

protected void DropDownList9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
        box22.Text = box22.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");
        TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
        TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
        box26.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box18.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box10.Text)).ToString();
    }
}


//For Button Click...
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addnewrow();

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share aspx and code behind

Comment: ya sure @SameieyMehdi..But Incomplete code is useless..After complete this code I will share.

Comment: Add some code here..No code then no help..!

Comment: @Mathi Call your addnewrow() function on submit for update your dtCurrentTable and then using for loop of dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count you can update all records one by one in database. And every loop you can calculate Total and finally you can store it to database.

Comment: @Mathi you need to skip SetPreviousData(); function when call addnewrow() on submit...

Answer (score 0):

Mathi,

Call your `addnewrow()` function on `submit` for update your `dtCurrentTable` and then using for loop of `dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count-1` you can update all records one by one in database.

For loop is like below..

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

And every loop you can calculate Total and finally you can store it to database.

To get Total do below code in addnewrow() function...

```
    decimal totalAmt = 0.00M;

    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        ///////// -----> end of the for loop

      if(box24.text.trim() == "")
          box24.text = "0";
      if(box25.text.trim() == "")
          box25.text = "0";
      if(box26.text.trim() == "")
          box26.text = "0";

        totalAmt = totalAmt + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box24.Text));
        totalAmt = totalAmt + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box25.Text));            
        totalAmt = totalAmt + Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(box26.Text));
    }

    TextBox box30 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Total Textbox ID");
    box30.Text = Convert.ToString(totalAmt);
```

Comment: Sorry @VishalPatel.. I had little mistake in my question.. When I am clicking the "add" button need to calculate the Total in loop wise and  then When I am clicking the "Submit"  button need to store all values to database.

Comment: @Mathi you can calculate `Total` in `addnewrow()` function. Take one variable and in `for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)`  loop you can calculate it one by one (three time (Amount1 * Rate1) in each loop) and finally after for loop you need to just assign it to Total Textbox and on submit you need to fetch Total textbox value and store it  to database..

Comment: @Mathi Is it fine with you or still have any query?

Comment: your explanation is good @VishalPatel.. but I don't know how to start it.. if you don't mine can you give a coding for total..

Comment: @Mathi This answer is Useful to you...?

Comment: @Mathi Could you please update me, r u satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Sorry @VishalPatel.. I don't want to multiply the boxes..just want to make the Amount total in that Total Textbox when I am clicking the Total Textbox...Now I updated my GridView design.. look at this.. now you can understand well.

Comment: @Mathi I have changed my code.. Could you please review and apply... ? If still you have any query then please let me know...

Comment: I have added my code... still the grand total was not calculated... and when I am clicking the "add" button next row was created but all values in a cell must to fill otherwise it shown error "Input string was not in a correct format"... now I posted my updated code.. please review and give a solution..

Comment: @Mathi I have updated my code... So could you please try it...?

Comment: Sorry @VishalPatel... I tried with your updated coding...But it was not working.. I added one question with updated coding.. Just refer this link and give a solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544038/how-to-do-multiple-cells-in-a-single-row-column-using-gridview-control

Comment: @Mathi Could you please let me know, that your all row amount column getting perfect value? if yes then now you need to just get Tatal of Amount column.. right?

Comment: @Mathi I didn't earn from this Question... And I have tried and may be useful to you. So please explain clearly what you want.