# How to do multiple cells in a single row column using GridView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Here I am using GridView Control.. My output screen is this..

[image]

My Coding is..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("S.No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Article No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Order Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UOM", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rate", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Currency", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["S.No"] = 1;
        dr["Article No"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Item Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Order Quantity"] = 0;
        dr["UOM"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Rate"] = 0.00;
        dr["Currency"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = 0.00;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
        box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
        box2.DataValueField = "Description";
        box2.DataBind();
        box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        
        DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box12.DataTextField = "Name";
        box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box12.DataBind();
        box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box13.DataTextField = "Name";
        box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box13.DataBind();
        box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
        box14.DataTextField = "Name";
        box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box14.DataBind();
        box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");
    }
}


public void addnewrow()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        

        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //extract the TextBox values
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
            TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
            TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
            TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
            Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
            TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
            TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
            TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
            Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
            DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
            Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
            TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
            TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
            TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
            Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
            DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
            DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
            DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
            Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
            TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
            TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
            TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");

            TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["S.No"] = i + 1;
           

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Article No"] = box2.Text;
         
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box3.Text + "," + box4.Text + "," + box5.Text + "," + box6.Text;
           
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Order Quantity"] = box8.Text + "," + box9.Text + "," + box10.Text;
           
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["UOM"] = box12.Text + "," + box13.Text + "," + box14.Text;
           
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Rate"] = box16.Text + "," + box17.Text + "," + box18.Text;
           
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Currency"] = box20.Text + "," + box21.Text + "," + box22.Text;
         
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Amount"] = box24.Text + "," + box25.Text + "," + box26.Text;
           

            rowIndex++;
        }

        
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dtCurrentTable;

        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
            box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
            box2.DataValueField = "Description";
            box2.DataBind();
            box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box12.DataTextField = "Name";
            box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box12.DataBind();
            box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box13.DataTextField = "Name";
            box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box13.DataBind();
            box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

            DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
            box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSimpleUnitItemInfo();
            box14.DataTextField = "Name";
            box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
            box14.DataBind();
            box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");
        }        
    }
    SetPreviousData();
}

private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
                Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
                TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
                TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
                Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
                DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
                Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
                TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
                TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
                TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
                Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
                DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
                DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
                DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
                Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
                TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
                TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
                TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");

                TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["S.No"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Article No"].ToString();
               
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box3.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box4.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box5.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                    box6.Text = strDesc[3].ToString();
                }
               
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Order Quantity"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Order Quantity"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box8.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box9.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box10.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }
                
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["UOM"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["UOM"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box12.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box13.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box14.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }
               
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Rate"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Rate"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box16.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box17.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box18.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }
            
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Currency"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Currency"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box20.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box21.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box22.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                }
             
                if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Amount"]).Trim() != "")
                {
                    string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Amount"]).Trim().Split(',');
                    box24.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
                    box25.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
                    box26.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
                                           
                }
                                                 
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

//DropDownList Selection Change..
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
   
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box3.Text = box2.SelectedItem.Value;
        }
    
}


protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.Text = box12.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.Text = box13.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.Text = box14.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}


protected void DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    decimal a = 0.00M;
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
        box20.Text = box20.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
        TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
        TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
        TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

        box24.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box16.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box8.Text)).ToString();
        if (a != null)
        {
            box27.Text = (a + Convert.ToDecimal(box24.Text)).ToString();
            a = Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            a = 0.00M;
        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    decimal b = 0.00M;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
        box21.Text = box21.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
        TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
        TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
        TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

        box25.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box17.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box9.Text)).ToString();
        if (b != null)
        {
            box27.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(box25.Text)).ToString();
            b = Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            b = 0.00M;
        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];

    decimal c = 0.00M;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
        box22.Text = box22.SelectedItem.Value;

        TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");
        TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
        TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
        TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

        box26.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box18.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box10.Text)).ToString();

        if (c != null)
        {
            box27.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(box26.Text)).ToString();
            c = Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            c = 0.00M;
        }
    }
}


//For Button Click...
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addnewrow();
}
```

Here When I am entering the first row 3 "Amount" cell control in the row is working fine..here I can reduce the cell count values in the row..
when I am entering the next rows I need to enter more than cell count which is in previous row cell count.. otherwise I am getting a error like "Input string was not in correct format"..

And the total also calculated based on the previous row cells..
If entering all the 3 cell values in every row means its working well..
if I am getting the error at the screen shot stage means it's calculating only 1'st cell values in all the rows..

If i have 1'st row 3 values and 2'nd row 2 values means it's calculating the 2 cell values in the each previous rows..
Based on this manner it's working.. how to do this? anyone help me to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In this Code where you calculate the Amount and assign to all three Amount textbox for each row? I didn't getting the code which calculate Amount (Amount column). Once we calculate Amount then after we can able to get Total Amount (Sum of Amount column).

Comment: The Amount and Total was calculated In DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged, DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged,DropDownList9_SelectedIndexChanged events @VishalPatel..

Comment: You might already know, basically, you should not assign such a confusion creatable name to variables and functions.

Comment: ya correct @JumpeiTanaka.. But The problem is not in variable creation.. It May be in loop.. I don't know where and how to implement.. the main problem is in sub rows.. when I am entering a next row it should equal or less than that in the previous sub row.. Otherwise it showing an error..

Answer (score 0):

Please change code as like below within for loop of all three dropdown events

- `DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged`
- `DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged`
- `DropDownList9_SelectedIndexChanged`

  to get Total of Amount Column....

Replace your below code in above three event...

```
TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");
TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

box26.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box18.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box10.Text)).ToString();

if (c != null)
{
    box27.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(box26.Text)).ToString();
    c = Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text);
}
else
{
    c = 0.00M;
}
```

### with below code...

```
TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
        TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
        TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");

        TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23"); // Second Control of Amount Column
        TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24"); // Third Control of Amount Column

        TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18"); // Second control of Rate Column
        TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14"); // Second control of Order quantity Column

        TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19"); // Third control of Rate Column
        TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15"); // Third control of Order quantity Column

        TextBox box27 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox24");

        box24.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box16.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box8.Text)).ToString();
        box25.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box17.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box9.Text)).ToString();
        box26.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(box18.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(box10.Text)).ToString();

        if (a != null)
        {
            box27.Text = (a + Convert.ToDecimal(box24.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(box25.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(box26.Text)).ToString();
            a = Convert.ToDecimal(box27.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            a = 0.00M;
        }
```

Comment: when this event fire @VishalPatel.. Where I want to give this code.. within the addnewrow() function or some other event.. if some other event means what is that.. Now I set one default(0.00) values to all textboxes so that "Input string was not incorrect" exception was cleared..

Comment: The code within the "dropdownlist_selectionChanged" itself working fine.. but the total was not perfect.. if I filled all the 3 sub rows means it is working fine.. if I did not filled 3'rd sub row in any one of the row  other than all sub rows in the rows are filled means first 2 sub row values only calculated..  if I did not filled the 2'nd and 3'rd sub row in any one of the row  other than all sub rows in the rows are filled means all 1'st sub rows values only calculated.. now you may clear about my question @VishalPatel..

Comment: It was not working @VishalPatel.. Please give some other solution to solve my problem.

Comment: @Mathi What you want? I will understand in detail.. step 1) enter all value in first row. 2) click on Add button : 2A) save all entered value in DataTable variable (with Total Amount : which I have already give the solution) 2B) create new row and finaly bind first row all column values by DataTable variable (using SetPreviousData(); function)..... This is whole thing make working your code... and Dropdown selected value change event also manage Total Amount but only worked on Dropdown selected value change event.

Comment: @Mathi Please let me know if I am wrong.. and it is perfect then you are missing something or doing not those thing perfectly which I have told you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43130/discussion-between-mathi-and-vishal-patel)